# Realm object server sync on low connection.

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-object-server

i have an realm object server and tries to sync data with android device like:

```
SyncCredentials syncCred = SyncCredentials
            .usernamePassword(username, password, false);
SyncUser.loginAsync(syncCred, url, new SyncUser.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(SyncUser user) {
        ...some code...
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(ObjectServerError error) {}
```

it works just fine with `wi-fi` but in case on low Internet connection (for example set up `GSM` network type for emulator) i got an error (`onError (ObjectServerError error)` calls):

```
java.net.ProtocolException: unexpected end of stream
at okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream$FixedLengthSource.read(Http1xStream.java:380)
at okio.Buffer.writeAll(Buffer.java:993)
at okio.RealBufferedSource.readByteArray(RealBufferedSource.java:106)
at okhttp3.ResponseBody.bytes(ResponseBody.java:128)
at okhttp3.ResponseBody.string(ResponseBody.java:154)
at io.realm.internal.network.AuthenticateResponse.from(AuthenticateResponse.java:51)
at io.realm.internal.network.OkHttpAuthenticationServer.authenticate(OkHttpAuthenticationServer.java:125)
at io.realm.internal.network.OkHttpAuthenticationServer.loginUser(OkHttpAuthenticationServer.java:53)
at io.realm.SyncUser.login(SyncUser.java:199)
at io.realm.SyncUser$1.run(SyncUser.java:234)
at io.realm.SyncUser$Request$1.run(SyncUser.java:585)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

at io.realm.internal.network.AuthenticateResponse.from(AuthenticateResponse.java:53)
at io.realm.internal.network.OkHttpAuthenticationServer.authenticate(OkHttpAuthenticationServer.java:125)
at io.realm.internal.network.OkHttpAuthenticationServer.loginUser(OkHttpAuthenticationServer.java:53)
at io.realm.SyncUser.login(SyncUser.java:199)
at io.realm.SyncUser$1.run(SyncUser.java:234)
at io.realm.SyncUser$Request$1.run(SyncUser.java:585)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

is it possible to sync data via low Internet connection?

Comment: Thanks for reporting this! it will be fixed by https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/5447

Comment: @beeender, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the [issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/5447) have been fixed in [4.1.0](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)